# Read/write .bdf files in Python and filter rows

Tags: python

I want to read specific rows from a .bdf file, modify them and then write them into a new file. Those are the ones which start with GRID, GRID* and * (example given below)

```
GRID*    1185                           26.875          -2.6516504287719
*       -6.875
GRID*    1186                           26.25           -1.7677669525146
*       -6.25
GRID*    1187                           25.625          -.88388347625732
*       -5.625
GRID     1189           -25.     0.     -5.
GRID     1190           -23.75   0.     -5.
GRID     1191           -22.5    0.     -5.
GRID     1192           -21.25   0.     -5.
```

Afterwards I want to modify some data from them and put it into another file, keeping the same format and order as before (else NASTRAN won't read the file correctly, it requires 8 character sintax). Any suggestions?

Comment: What is your question, exactly?

Comment: My idea is to store rows as vectors and then make operations on them (I want to increase/decrease their quantities randomly in a range). After this, I want to put the results with the same format in a new file. Is it possible?